# trying to use the count statement to count numerous values for multiple individulas

Tags: sql, select, count

I work for a community health center.  I'm trying to count how many times each of our dental providers utilized multiple service codes.  Trying to create a script that would return something similar to the below:

```
provider|code|code|code etc...
---------------------------
name    | #  | #  | #
---------------------------
name    | #  | #  | #
---------------------------
name    | #  | #  | #
---------------------------
etc...
```

I've already had a script that returned what Im looking for but not in the format I need

```
select pm.description [Provider], p.service_item_id [Code], p.service_item_description [Service], COUNT(pm.description) As Count
from patient_procedure p 
     inner join location_master l on p.location_id = l.location_id 
     inner join provider_master pm on p.provider_id = pm.provider_id
     inner join patient_encounter p2 on p.enc_id = p2.enc_id
where l.location_name like '%dental%'
      and p2.enc_timestamp between '20190101 00:00:00.000' and '20190630 23:59:59.999'
      and p2.billable_ind = y
group by p.service_item_id, p.service_item_description, pm.description
order by p.service_item_description ASCENDING
```

It returns:

```
Provider| Code| Service| Count
```

Comment: What database?  SQL Server?  Please edit your question and add a `sql-server` or whatever database.  Also, looks like you want to pivot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get different counts for each code, you can use a conditional `COUNT` statement:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN service_item_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_id_1
```

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
  pm.description [Provider], 
  p.service_item_id [Code], 
  p.service_item_description [Service], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.service_item_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Count_id_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.service_item_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Count_id_2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.service_item_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Count_id_3
FROM patient_procedure p 
     INNER JOIN location_master l ON p.location_id = l.location_id 
     INNER JOIN provider_master pm ON p.provider_id = pm.provider_id
     INNER JOIN patient_encounter p2 ON p.enc_id = p2.enc_id
WHERE l.location_name LIKE '%dental%'
     AND p2.enc_timestamp BETWEEN '20190101 00:00:00.000' AND '20190630 23:59:59.999'
     AND p2.billable_ind = y
GROUP BY p.service_item_id, p.service_item_description, pm.description
ORDER BY p.service_item_description ASCENDING
```

This will give you the `COUNTs` for as many different codes you want to track.

Comment: Thank you for that! But it looks like using that becomes tedious as ill continue to have to add a CASE for each code which we have 100+ of.  Any way to make it so it would count as many service items that we have.  Something like a DISTINCT statement?

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure, maybe look at doing a `PIVOT` as suggested by Mark in the comments above.